# Destroying some records takes a really, really long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `Product` model that `has_many` `ProductAttributes` in a Rails 4.2.3 application.

A `Product` can have over 10,000 ProducAttributes sometimes.

I need to delete some of these products, but when I call `destroy` on the product, it takes a really, really long time. It looks like it gets a list of ids from `ProductAttribute`, then called delete on each one individually.

But then when it gets to the end, it just sort of hangs. I have a lot of data to delete, and occasionally I will need to do this.

But I can't just have this thing hang forever. Eventually I have to do a `Ctrl-C`, after which time I see `Rollback` happening.

My question is, what in the heck is it doing? Why can't I reliably delete lots of data from the application layer?

Comment: Have you looked at [this possible dupe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680656/why-is-activerecord-destroy-all-taking-so-long)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you use something like

```
has_many :product_attributes, dependent: :destroy
```

You might want to look into using [`dependent: :delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797358/473467) so Rails doesn't instantiate all dependent records before destroying them individually.

The [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) will have more information about consequences (e.g. if callbacks are executed on the dependent models etc.)